# Get doubles with combination and group by

Tags: sql

I create test table:

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTable(
LoginName varchar(500),
FullName varchar(500),
mobilephone varchar(500))
```

Fill in the table:

```
insert into #TempTable
select 'guid1', 'FullName1', 'mobilephone1'
union select 'guid2', 'FullName1', 'mobilephone1'
union select 'guid3', 'FullName2', 'mobilephone2'
union select 'guid4', '------', 'mobilephone2'
union select 'guid5', 'FullName3', 'mobilephone3'
union select 'guid6', 'FullName3', 'mobilephone3'
union select 'guid7', 'FullName4', 'mobilephone4'
union select 'guid8', '------', 'mobilephone4'
```

I need select doubles by mobilephone where first FullName is valid and second FullName = '------'
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this will do what you want:

```
select mobilephone
from #temptable
group by mobilephone
having sum(case when FullName <> '------' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when FullName = '------' then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

SQL tables represent unordered sets so there is no concept of "first" and "second" unless a column is used for ordering (typically an id or creation date column).  The above query just returns all mobile phones that have at least one valid name and one name consisting only of hyphens.

Answer (score 0):

Which DBMS are you using? Different DBMS handle this differently. You are looking for numbers for which both an entry '------' and another exist. A set intersection.

```
select mobilephone from #TempTable where LoginName = '------'
INTERSECT
select mobilephone from #TempTable where LoginName <> '------';
```